# Will a recursive sha256 run over all 2^256 inputs before a collision?

Tags: hash, sha256, key-collision

Will a recursive sha256 run over all 2^256 inputs before a collision?

Here'a a python program showing my question - will this loop for 2^256 times - given endless memory or will it terminate before - if so when?

```
import hashlib

# start with 0
input = (0).to_bytes(32, byteorder="little", signed=False)

# dictionary to detect hash collisions - yes, this will eat up ALL memory
hit = {}

print ("first input:" + input.hex())

while (1):
    hash = hashlib.sha256(input).digest()
    
    # do we have a collision?
    assert (hash not in hit), "Collision!"
    
    # store current hash
    hit[hash]=1

    print ("Hash: " + hash.hex())

    # try again with the hash output as input
    input=hash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you will "probably" find a collision after `2^128` attempts.

The concept you are looking for is called the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), explained also very well in [this video by Professor Christoph Parr](https://youtu.be/tLkHk__-M6Q?t=3176).

One of the approximations from The Birthday Problem is that given a random output space of size `n`, the probability of an input collision approaches 50% after approximately `√n` attempts. `(2^256)^1/2 = 2^128`